# Button to redirect to another page and automatically pop modal

Tags: html, jquery

I have a button on a page (page 2) that links to another page (page 1). On page 1 I have a modal. How would one set the button on page 2 to link to page 1, and automatically pop the modal. I understand a normal link would be `href='/page1'`, I have tried `href='/page1#modal'`, but this does not work. I am running jQuery if this would be the route to go - I have seen some solutions around this but very  outdated.

If this is even possible, any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: You check if the url contains the `modal` keyword and then call the function to open the modal window. if you don't have a function yet you can also "fake" the click on the button which does open the modal window with https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ or vanilla javascript "trigger click event"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `#modal` part to the `href` in page2, and check URL on page1 load and if it contains `#modal`, show modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#modal') > -1)
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, although the snippet does not work it this answer helped me with the logic of going about it - I will figure it out. I will mark your answer

Comment: glad I could  help , If you replace `#mymodal` with your modal id , i think it will work.